# why are my substrings not being added to my queue?

Tags: java, queue

the program I am working on is supposed to have you enter a gender and name of a person ex: "m john"
And then it is supposed to separate the males and females and print out just the name separately.

I have am comparing the first character in the string  and then using enqueue to add a substring to either a male queue or a female queue and then I am trying to print each queue by printing the dequeued substring. but I get an error that my queue is empty even though I have added strings in my for loop.

```
public class GenderSorter 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int numElements;
        int maleCount = 0;
        int femaleCount = 0;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many people are you adding: ");
        numElements = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();

        ArrayBndQueue male = new ArrayBndQueue<>();
        ArrayBndQueue female = new ArrayBndQueue<>();

        for(int index = 1; index <= numElements; index++)
        {
            /*
            System.out.println("Enter a gender and name (ex: f jenny)");
            String name = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println(name);
            */
            System.out.println("Enter a gender and name (ex: f jenny)");
            String name = keyboard.nextLine();
            char character = name.charAt(0);
            if(character == 'f')
            {
                female.enqueue(name.substring(2));
                femaleCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                male.enqueue(name.substring(2));
                maleCount++;
            }
        }   

            System.out.println("Females: " + "\n");
            for(int index2 = 0; index2 <= femaleCount; index2++)
            {
                System.out.print(female.dequeue());
            }

            System.out.println("Males: " + "\n");
            for(int index3 = 0; index3 <= maleCount; index3++)
            {
                System.out.print(male.dequeue());
            }
    }  
}
```

Here is my ArrayBndQueue:

```
public class ArrayBndQueue<T> implements BoundedQueueInterface<T> 
{
    protected final int DEFCAP = 100;
    protected T[] queue;
    protected int numElements = 0;
    protected int front = 0;
    protected int rear;

    public ArrayBndQueue()
    {
        queue = (T[]) new Object[DEFCAP];
        rear = DEFCAP -1;
    }

    public ArrayBndQueue(int maxSize)
    {
        queue = (T[]) new Object[maxSize];
        rear = maxSize -1;
    }

    public void enqueue(T element)
    {
        if(isFull())
        {
            throw new QueueOverflowException("Enqueue " + "attempted on full queue");
        }
        else
        {
            rear = (rear + 1) % queue.length;
            queue[rear] = element;
            numElements++;
        }
    }

    public boolean isFull()
    {
        return (numElements == queue.length);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (numElements == 0);
    }

    public T dequeue()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            throw new QueueUnderflowException("Dequeue" + 
                    " attempted on empty queue!");
        }
        else
        {
            T toReturn = queue[front];
            queue[front] = null;
            front = (front + 1) % queue.length;
            numElements--;
            return toReturn;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's not the only problem, but

`for(int index2 = 0; index2 <= femaleCount; index2++)`

should be

`for(int index2 = 0; index2 < femaleCount; index2++)`

As it is, the last dequeue would give you the `QueueUnderflowException`, since you are trying to dequeue n+1 items from a queue that contains only n.

Same problem exists for both male and female loops.